# Convert string to xml in C#

Tags: xml

I have build some xml tag using Stringbuilder. This Stringbuilder string I want to convert as string in XML format using C#. Below I have specified input string and expected output string.

EX:

```
Input:
      <Configuration Id="5020244c-42c4-4a3c-af16-806d8948c7fd" Name="ACTDrawing" Landscape="True" PaperKind="A3" IsNewConfiguration="true"><Worksheets><WorkSheet Name="OVERVIEW" Zoom="100" Lock="False" Default="True"> <Page Id="7eba0912-51bf-4ffe-ac65-6ac495fa5af6" Number="1" Lock="False"></WorkSheet></Worksheets></Configuration>

Expected Output:
      <Configuration Id=\"5020244c-42c4-4a3c-af16-806d8948c7fd\" Name=\"ACTDrawing\" Landscape=\"True\" PaperKind=\"A3\" IsNewConfiguration=\"true\"><Worksheets><WorkSheet Name=\"OVERVIEW\" Zoom=\"100\" Lock=\"False\" Default=\"True\"><Page Id=\"7eba0912-51bf-4ffe-ac65-6ac495fa5af6\" Number=\"1\" Lock=\"False\"></WorkSheet></Worksheets></Configuration>
```

I have done code for this conversion.

Ex :

```
    StringBuilder ACTConfigXML = new StringBuilder();
ACTConfigXML.Append("<Configuration Id=\"");
ACTConfigXML.Append(System.Guid.NewGuid());
ACTConfigXML.Append("\" Name=\"ACTDrawing\" " +
    "Landscape=\"True\" PaperKind=\"A3\" " +
    "IsNewConfiguration=\"true\">");
ACTConfigXML.Append("<Worksheets>");
ACTConfigXML.Append("<WorkSheet Name=\"");
ACTConfigXML.Append(_WorkSheetName.ToString());
ACTConfigXML.Append("\" Zoom=\"100\" Lock=\"False\" Default=\"False\">");
ACTConfigXML.Append("</WorkSheet>");
ACTConfigXML.Append("</Worksheets></Configuration>");

XmlDocument _ACTGraphicalXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
_ACTGraphicalXMLDoc.LoadXml(ACTConfigXML.ToString());
ACTConfigXML = new StringBuilder();
ACTConfigXML.Append(_ACTGraphicalXMLDoc.OuterXml);
string configXML = ACTConfigXML.ToString();
```

In this example I don't want to use "_ACTGraphicalXMLDoc.OuterXml" for formatting. I want to convert "ACTConfigXML" data to Expected format.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your input, then just save it as an XML file.  You don't need the escaped double quotes in XML (you only need that if you are putting in a literal in your program).  Your question doesn't explain what you have tried, etc.  nor does it address the end goal.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, it looks like string.replace() might do the trick

```
output = input.replace("{", "\"");
output = output.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save your string with *XmlDocument*

Answer (score 0):

It's rarely a good idea to build a document from strings.  You're setting yourself up for XML errors if the "_WorkSheetName.ToString()" contains anything that will break XML (like a "/>...)
Create a template XML document in a string or disk file, load into DOM with XmlDomDocument.loadXML, update the values / attributes you need.  For example

```
string strXML = @"
<Configuration id='to be replaced' Landscape='True' PaperKind='A3' IsNewConfiguration='true'>
    <Worksheets>
        <Worksheet Name='to be replaced' Zoom='100' Lock='False' Default='False'/>
    </Worksheets>
</Configuration>";

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml( strXML );
XmlElement ndElement = xml.DocumentElement;
ndElement.SetAttribute( "id", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() );

XmlElement ndWorksheet = (XmlElement)xml.SelectSingleNode( "/Configuration/Worksheets/Worksheet" );
if( ndWorksheet != null ) {
    ndWorksheet.SetAttribute("Name", "Safe worksheet name <>'\"/>");
}

xml.Save( Response.OutputStream );
```